# Minimum files needed to deploy webAPI server side

Tags: c#, wcf, service, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

So after a great deal of research I'm starting to enhance our service server stack with a webAPI entry point.  Based on [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1772347.aspx/1), and especially the last post by a member of the Digerati board, we are implementing webAPI services as a facade into our WCF application layer.  (Our WCF services are just facades into our Application layer where all of the behavior lives)

My question is this.  I downloaded MVC 4 and created a new WebAPI project in my service solution.  But wow there was a ton of crap that created in my project that I just am not going to need!  For example, all of the image files, the home controller, views and models, etc.

So in stripping this down to be just a service project, what are the minimum files I need to build a functional service project?  Our intent is to publish both of the service types (WCF and webAPI) side by side in the same server .. each service call doing the same identical service call and returning the specific DTO for the request.  So far it looks like App_Start, Controllers, and the Glabal.asax/web.config entries.  I definitely don't need Views, Models, or Images!!!

Any input on what others have done to do a pure service deployment would be of great welcome here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Same problem here. I've found that **[article](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/05/10/Creating-a-minimal-Web-API-web-project.aspx)** from Shawn Kendrot explaining how to create minimal Web API project. It was written for the beta version of Web API but it seems to be still valid.

1. Create an empty ASP.NET project.
2. Add a reference to `System.Web.Http` and `System.Web.Http.WebHost` (version 4.0.0.0)
3. Add a `Global.asax` file
4. Register a route in the `Global.Application_Start`. Something like:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
   }
   ```
5. Add a controller

   ```
   public class SampleController : ApiController
   {
     public string Get(int id)
     {
       return "Hello";
     }
   }
   ```

   6. Run the project locally with the URL `/api/sample/123` and enjoy the outcome:

[image]

Comment: +1 This should really be somewhere in the official documentation!

Comment: LOL there is quit a bit that should be in the official documenation.  +1 to your comment.  :)

Answer (score 3):

FYI.  I have found that I have had to reference two more .dlls:

- System.Net.Http
- Newtonsoft.Json