# Required to install asp.net ("Application Server") when deploying WebApi to server 2012?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm new to WebAPI in .Net 4.5.  Probably my question is an FAQ, but I couldn't find how to solve it:
Do I need to add the `application server` role in addition to IIS to have an IIS hosted WebApi application run on server 2012?  I believe that .Net 4.5 is already there in 2012, but do I also have to install the role `asp.net`?

Closest thing I could find on this question is:

- [Minimum files needed to deploy webAPI server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412163/minimum-files-needed-to-deploy-webapi-server-side)

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12704353/463785

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  We were planning on bin deploying WebAPI, but since it is technically called "Asp.Net MVC WebAPI" I think (not a great name by the way :-)), it begs the question of whether you need Asp.net support installed on IIS.  Thanks again.  Answered.

Comment: It's not called "ASP.NET MVC Web API". It has nothing to do with MVC. It's one of the biggest misconceptions about the product. Have a look: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/newsflash-asp-net-web-api-does-not-sit-on-top-of-asp-net-mvc-in-fact-it-does-not-sit-on-top-of-anything

Comment: Hmmm...  Didnt know that - I can swear I see the string "ASP.Net MVC Web API" in quite a few places, so I just assumed.  Serves me right for assuming :-)  Thanks for clarifying